# SwiftUI Widget Locale doesn't apply

Tags: swift, swiftui, locale, ios14, widgetkit

I'm trying to localize the date in my widget, I want to use the **Italian locale** "it" that I already used elsewhere in my main application with this exact code but somehow, on my widget both on the simulator and on real devices the locale doesn't change

This is my date formatter in my `ViewModel`

```swift
static let dateFormat: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE dd"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "it")
    return formatter
}()
```

and this is how I format the date in my `View`

```swift
Text("\(viewModel.nextDay, formatter: ViewModel.dateFormat)")
```

Comment: Currently, the widget is not supported. If you change the system language then it will work.

Comment: My system language is Italian, but still doesn't work

Comment: Try to print current local

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use SwiftUI `locale` environment key, like

[image: demo]

```
Text(entry.date, style: .date)
    .bold()
    .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "it"))
```

Tested with Xcode 12.1

Comment: Do you have any idea, why the locale in the code you provided does not apply, when I change `style: .date` to `.offset` or `.relative`?